# VS Code doesn't support any .html files

Tags: html, visual-studio-code

[image: **enter image description here**]

Please help me. I installed all extensions for html. But it doesn't work. What is can i do.

Answer (score 1):

You have got your page in Django Template. Please change it to HTML! That should work.

[image: lang]

Answer (score 0):

You can change language mode on the bar below on the right from "Django Template" to "HTML" and it would work.

But if you want to use "Django Template" you can add this to your settings.json file:

```
"emmet.includeLanguages": {
    ...
    "django-html": "html",
    ...
},
```

how to add it?
`ctrl + ,` 
then press on the third icon on the top right bar,
then add the code to the file and save it

<sorry, I can't add images because my reputation is less than 10 :*(>